# How to send javascript values as params without backslash

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am sending form input params as a hidden field, the value is appending from javascript. After sending values from javascript and on click on form submit it is automatically adding a backslash to it. Please help me to avoid it.

Here are my params passing screenshot.

> Started PATCH "/admins/resources/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-13 15:35:28 +0530
>   Processing by Admins::ResourcesController#update as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PJDlGucD+gQ6ki9AMcxFVO7Wd4fEM6vrfyaLSjQvd+Eog3fXpiAeyayaI2j2wnucjZPZezpfBcWo4P30M6684A==", "resource"=>{ "subcategory_ids"=>["\"15\",\"4\",\"8\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\","]}, "commit"=>"Update Resource", "id"=>"1"}

Here you can see subcategory arrays getting with backslash included. i want it just like this 
"subcategory_ids"=>["15","4","8","5","6","7"]}

Please help me to get like this

Here is my javascript

```js
 var dids;
      var result=[];
      $('#versionsDiv').on('change', function(e) {
        var dids = $(this).val();
        console.log(ids);
        var result = dids;
        console.log(dids)
        var x = result 
        call_me(x);
        function call_me(params) {
         var array=[];
         for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) { 
          array+=  '"'+ params[i] + '"' +',';  
          console.log(array);
        }
        jQuery("#resource_subcategory_ids").val(array);
      }
    });
```

here is my form is hidden

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "resource[subcategory_ids][]", [], id: "resource_subcategory_ids", :multiple=>"true" %>
```

Comment: what is the result of that `console.log(array);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which part of your system is escaping quotemarks. At some point a string is stringified. For illustration:

```
const arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
const str = '"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"';
const obj = {'id': 1, 'text': str, 'arr': arr};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

/******result************************
["1","2","3","4","5"]
"\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\""
{"id":1,"text":"\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\"","arr":["1","2","3","4","5"]}
/************************************/
```

For solution: try to post your data (dids/result/x/params) as an array, don't stringify it (mm.. i assume that you are aware that your variable "array" is a string although you create it as an array?).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `regular expression` to remove the unwanted backslashes before passing the array to `.val()`

```
array.forEach(function(item, i) {
item.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
});
jQuery("#resource_subcategory_ids").val(array);
```

Try this `regex` on [regex101](https://regex101.com/). The `g` flag here stands for `global` which says that the expression needs to be replaced `gloablly`.

Read more on `.replace()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)